# Invisible powershell script to create local admin account with secured password

Tags: windows, powershell, admin, administrator

I'm not very familiar with stackoverflow nor with Powershell.
Sorry for formatting, please let me know how to improve my post for more visibility.

I've been trying to get an invisible powershell script who will check if the account exists before creating it.
If the account doesn't exists, then the script would create a local administrator account part of administrator group with a secured password.
The account would be forced to change password on next login.

I've already tried a couple of things, i'm having 2 separated scripts, one to create the secured password in a .txt file then i'm calling this file into the main script.

So far the script is not silent (invisible) and the password is not saved.
The account is indeed created but when I enter the password it says I have an error.
If I set the password in an unsecured way It would work and ask me to change it on next login.

Unfortunately, if the account already exists it doesn't quit the script, instead it changes the password.

Password creation:

`Read-Host -Prompt "Saisir mot de passe " -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File C:\script2\init.pwd`

Main script:

```
$Password = cat C:\script2\init.pwd | ConvertTo-SecureString

$group = "Administrators"

$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$existing = $adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' -and $_.Name -eq $Username }

if ($existing -eq $Username) {
        exit
}
else {
        NET USER $Username $Password /add /y /expires:never
        NET LOCALGROUP $group $Username /add

}

$Username = "su"
$Usrstring = "WinNT://localhost/"+$Username  
$usr=[ADSI] $Usrstring  
$usr.passwordExpired = 1  
$usr.setinfo()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `try-catch` method and `New-localuser` to do this.

```
$username = "TestUser"
$Password = cat C:\script2\init.pwd | ConvertTo-SecureString
#Changing this back to what would work for you. I was supplying a plaintext password
#$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Password" -AsSecureString

try
{
    Get-LocalUser -Name $username -ErrorAction Stop
    #"User Already exists"
}
catch
{
    New-LocalUser -Name $username -Password $Password
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $username

    $usr=[ADSI]"WinNT://localhost/$username"
    $usr.passwordExpired = 1
    $usr.setinfo()
}
```

If this is saved as a script say `Create-localUser.ps1` you can invoke this from `Run`, `Task Scheduler` or a `logon batch script` using the command

`powershell.exe -windowstyle Hidden -file C:\temp\create-Localuser.ps1`

And keep it hidden from the logged on user. I assumed thats what you meant by invisible.

Comment: Hey Rohin thank you for your answer, I didn't know about try/catch duo.

I tried your way but I have some errors saying that I am not able to use New-LocalUser because the password lenght, complexity requirements are not meet.

However I know it does, maybe it's an issue when I call my init.txt file where the password is stored.

Comment: @FrançoisBillard As I mentioned in my script, I used a plaintext password as input, hence I had the extra `-asplaintext` and `-force` switch added. I believe you are using an encrypted  text in `init.pwd`. So you probably wouldn't need those. Encrypted text is usually a very long string of text and hence you are getting the `password length` error. So for you, this line should be sufficient:`$Password = cat C:\script2\init.pwd | ConvertTo-SecureString`

Comment: @FrançoisBillard I have edited it. See if that works.

Comment: @FrançoisBillard I also wanted to ask you, how are you creating the `init.pwd` file? If the file is not created on the target machine, it will probably become unreadable.

Comment: Hey Rohin sorry for the delayed response, thank you so much for your help, indeed I was trying to use an encrypted text in init.pwd which was the reason why it didn't worked.
I didn't expect it to be an issue as I thought it is not secured to have the password in plain text in the script.
However it appear that It didn't worked until I put my password in plain text as you suggested. 
So everything is working now, thank you for your precious help :)
By any chance do you know if it would be possible to have some logs created on my server every time the script is used ?

Comment: Adding logging is just a matter of doing this every now and then. `"User Exists" | out-file C:\temp\log.txt -append` , `"User created" | out-file C:\temp\log.txt -append`. You can add code to verify these things before they are logged.

Comment: Also, you can use an encrypted password, if ur environment demands it. Just make sure that you change ur code to suit it. One way I make sure that I get the passwords correctly in my scripts is by creating a temp `PScredential` Object like `$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $Password`. Note that `$username` can be anything. We dont really care. `$Password` is supposed to be the secure string password.

Comment: @FrançoisBillard Now to verify that you have the `$password` in the right format, just do this: `$cred.GetNetworkCredential().password` It should return you the plaintext original password.